# .net assembly resolution handler fails in one machine but succeeds in another

Tags: .net, assembly-resolution, assemblyresolve

I have noticed differences in how .net resolves assemblies in 2 different machines. In one machine it seems to be doing it as it executes line-by-line and in another machine per method.

Lets say I have the following in `Test.dll`:

```
public class Test()
{
    static Test()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name == "Dep.dll")
        {
            return LocalMethodThatResolves(args); // local method in this class
        }
        else
        {
            return HelperInDependentAssembly.Resolve(args); // this method lives in Dep.dll
        }
    }
}
```

**what happens in good machine:**

the `Dep.dll` needs to be resolved so it enters the `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve` and then resolves it locally as being handled inside the `if` logic.

**what happens in bad machine:**

the `Dep.dll` needs to be resolved so before entering the resolve method, it notices there's a call to a method that lives in another assembly (which is the same `Dep.dll`) and eventually the `StackOverflowException`

can anyone explain as to why it happens?

(the code runs in .net 4.5)